# Как в Django CMS отображать разные страницы для разных городов?

Tags: django, geoip, django-cms

В Django CMS есть удобная сегментация по языкам, позволяющая забить в админке одну страницу разными данными для разных языков.
[image: Языковая сегментация]

Есть задача выводить разные данные на странице для разных городов. Хотелось бы что-то похожее на сегментацию по языкам. Но как не искал, ничего подобного не нашёл.

Единственное, что пришло пока в голову: поднять GeoIP на Nginx, настроить редирект на субдомены вида <city_name>.domain.com и эксплуатировать django sites framework. Но это не настолько изящный вариант, насколько хотелось бы.

Comment: [Django-geoip](http://django-geoip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/djangohosts.html) смотрели?

Comment: Пользуюсь им уже много лет. Вопрос не в том, как определять города. Вопрос в том, как сегментировать данные по городам так же просто, как по языкам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Невозможно сделать так, как мне хотелось. Да и других готовых решений для геосегментирования контента я не нашёл. Пришлось написать свой плагин - [djangocms-geoplaceholder](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangocms-geoplaceholder). Возможно, он пригодится кому-нибудь ещё.